# How can I configure the typeface of fontawesome in general for my CV using overleaf?

Tags: fonts, overleaf, moderncv, fontawesome, typefaces

I try to configure the typeface of fontawesome5 at my CV. The outcome is always the use of the fontawesome icons and symbols but the typeface for the CV stays the same. Here is the code of which I thought it would solve the problem:

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
```

In addition to that I uploaded the fontawesome5.sty and installed fontawesome5 on my laptop. I write my CV in german language. I also have an english version of my CV, but with the same configuration the problem remains the same. I also tried to change the compiler without success and my actual compiler is LuaLaTeX.

I am looking for a solution for so long now, that I would be ok with using a typeface looking similar to the fontawesome5 typeface.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) As far as I know, both of those packages provide only icon fonts, not text fonts. If you are using Overleaf, Overleaf is not able to see or use the fonts installed on your laptop. If you have fonts that you would like to use with your Overleaf projects that are licensed for this use, you can upload them to your project to use them in Overleaf. See [I have a custom font I'd like to load to my document. How can I do this?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F)

Comment: You can load only one of the two packages at a time, either `fontawesome` or `fontawesome5`. If you try to load both you should get all kinds of errors and after receiving errors the output will generally not be useful. That being said Paul's comment still applies: These are symbol fonts, the packages intentionally only make icons available.

Comment: @ Paul Gessler That worked well for me. I see know that using the typeface of fontawesome on Overleaf is possible, but there are no uncommon letters, like ä, ö, ü, ß. So I go on using times new roman or the default typeface.